# Rowcommand not firing for linkbutton in gridview?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

I have a gridview with a linkbutton. I set up a lightbox for the linkbutton using jquery and css.

Linkbutton source code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course" ItemStyle-CssClass="course" HeaderStyle-CssClass="course">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Course_Name" runat="server"   Text='<%# Eval("Course_Name__c") %>' ForeColor="#666699" CommandName="course" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'  ></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />

                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="course"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have to set the content of lightbox in rowcommand event.I use the following code in rowdatabound.

```
  cname.CssClass = "popup-with-zoom-anim";
        cname.Attributes.Add("href", "#smalldialog");
```

The script is,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',

            fixedContentPos: false,
            fixedBgPos: true,

            overflowY: 'auto',

            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,

            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
        });

        $('.popup-with-move-anim').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',

            fixedContentPos: false,
            fixedBgPos: true,

            overflowY: 'auto',

            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,

            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-slide-bottom'
        });
    });
</script>
```

But rowcommand not firing so lightbox displaying no data.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well there can be more than one reason for this behaviour. Perform the following checks:

1. Do NOT bind your `GridView` on postbacks in `Page_Load` event. Means to say if you are binding your GridView from Code behind, bind it only for first time::

   if ((!Page.IsPostback)) {
       GridView1.DataBind();
   }
2. Do NOT disable `ViewState` for `GridView`
3. Last option and Least expected is that `OnRowCommand`  attribute may be missing/not
   defined  in the  gridView markup. Make sure you have defined an event handler for your Row Command event, something as :

   `<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="Event_Handler_Here" .. />`